# .htaccess RewriteRule domain.com/page/page to domain.com?p=page/page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up my `.htaccess` file. How would I go about getting this result:

Request: `domain.com/page/page`

Rewrite to: `domain.com/index.php?p=page/page`

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

with no luck.

Comment: The page loads but it looks odd, maybe the style sheet isn't loading right? I'm not really sure.

Comment: by adding a slash: RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA] 
It loads okay but the pages don't work.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1
500 server error.

Comment: I think it's because I'm adding ?p= regardless of if there is a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I worked it out. I needed two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)(/)?$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)(/)?$ index.php?p=$1/$2
```

My php script didn't like it because with just

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)(/)?$ index.php?p=$1
```

domain.com/no1/ would translate into domain.com/index.php?p=no1/ <--- didn't understand the end slash

Only problem with this solution is it only goes two virtual dirs deep but as that's all I need it's fine.
This is my first time using .htaccess so I'm sorry for my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Negative lookahead will avoid infinite looping here.

Comment: Okay I worked it out. I needed two rules:

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)(/)?$ index.php?p=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)(/)?$ index.php?p=$1/$2

My php script didn't like it because with just

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\s-]+)(/)?$ index.php?p=$1

domain.com/no1/ would translate into domain.com/index.php?p=no1/ <--- didn't understand the end slash

Only problem with this solution is it only goes two virtual dirs deep but as that's all I need it's fine.
This is my first time using .htaccess so I'm sorry for my lack of understanding.